# Building a JTAG programmer for ATmega

Tags: atmega, programmer, jtag, ftdi

I want to program an ATmega over JTAG, but I would like to build the JTAG programmer myself.
Is it possible to program an ATmega128A by constructing a JTAG programmer [similar to this](http://vak.ru/doku.php/proj/bitbang/bitbang-jtag)?

It uses an [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) FTDI chip from one of these boards:

[image] [image]

Connected to a JTAG header like this:

[image]

If this is possible, what software would I use to program with?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a generic FT232 breakout board. LadyAda has [documented](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/breakoutplus/ftdifriend.html#programming_blank_avrs) a way for using one to program an AVR chip (using avrdude). But it is really slow, and requires patching the avrdude software. So it is useful for writing a boot loader to the AVR, which you then can use for uploading your programs.

There is [another guide](http://www.geocities.jp/arduino_diecimila/bootloader/index_en.html) which also provides some precompiled software based on avrdude (but as usual, beware with such software, and use a virtual machine to be sure).

But this only provides a way for programming the AVR. You don't get debugging capability that way. [OpenOCD](http://openocd.sf.net) provides preliminary support for the 8-bit AVR family, so you might want to try this. The OpenOCD configuration is already provided with the programmer you linked to.

Comment: it's ok, if it will be slow or doesn't have debugging capability, i just want to write flash memory

Comment: Then [avrdude-serjtag](http://www.geocities.jp/arduino_diecimila/bootloader/index_en.html) should work for you.